# Comparing ID's and pick the higher value

Tags: hana

I need your help in HANA. I'm trying to compare dates in different rows, like:

```
ID~~~~~~|~~~ NAME~~~|~DATE ~~ |   STEP
--------+-----------+---------+-----------
132~~~~~|~~TEST~~~| 01.01.2001| CREATED
132~~~~~|~~TEST~~~| 05.01.2001| SOLVED
154~~~~~|~~Other~~| 06.01.2001| CREATED
175~~~~~|~~Card~~~| 08.01.2001| CREATED
175~~~~~|~~ Card~~| 09.01.2001| SOLVED
```

So my problem is, I want to pick the row with the highest date in HANA, but I don't know how I could do that.

First I have to compare the ID's and pick the ID's which are double or more and then pick the ID with the highest date.

I would be grateful for your help.

Best regards

Comment: remove the unused db tag ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be works, not tested yet

`SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM table1 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: Yes it works but I can't add other columns after the SELECT-Statement, Like:

SELECT MAX(DATE), ID, STEP, NAME FROM table1 GROUP BY TID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

Comment: Now I understand why it doesn'tt work but I still have to filter the other ID's out which are double

Comment: Glad if it helped :) You can tick this as the answer

Comment: i think that should be cover all duplicate ID

Comment: In my Table I have to show all columns:

SELECT  ID, TOPICNAME, SUMMARY, CREATEDWHEN, STEPNAME, MAX(DATE), STEPNAME 
FROM Table1 GROUP BY TID, TOPICNAME, SUMMARY, CREATEDWHEN, STEPNAME HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

And in the table there are still double ID's, so for example there are two rows and they show different dates and one of them is higher than the other one.

With the date there is also a timestamp like: 20.09.2016 18:37:51.0.

Comment: i think it's because your `GROUP BY` columns, try to use only TID

Comment: If I only use TID, there always comes an error:
not a GROUP BY expression: 'Table.TOPICNAME' must be in group by clause.: line 1 col 13 (at pos 12)

Comment: still didn't work? maybe i can help you, send your structure and table data to my email, zaid.ug@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `GREATEST` function: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/greatest-function.php